# How to make pixel more visible in LIbgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, photoshop

I made a pixel art texture on photoshop which is 30x30 pixels, what I wanted to achieve is that the pixels are really visible like when its zoomed in photoshop, something like flappy bird where the character is really small but you can still see the pixel (I mean every square), on libgdx i resize it to 60x60 and it just comes out just ugly and doesn't seem to look like a pixel art.

```
//PPm = 30;
if(body.getUserData() != null && body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite && spr.equals(Ball.ballSpr)){
      batch.draw(spr, (wc.ballPos.x - 1) * PPM, (wc.ballPos.y - 1) * PPM, 2 * PPM, 2 * PPM);
            }
```

Comment: Make your texture 60x60 in photoshop instead?

Comment: Provide your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the filters for the texture so that it doesn't try to smooth them.

Something like...

```
myTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

Where `myTexture` is the texture you pass to the Sprite constructor (or the texture that the texture region is from).